# get content using partial text in p tag keyword in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my code. I want to get text content of Product name which is only "IDE" not " Product name: IDE".

```
  <div class="typeCategory">
  <p class="Type" >
    "
    Product name: IDE
    "
    <br>

    "
    Product Price: $499
    "

  </p>
```

Can anyone tell me how? 
Thanks!

Comment: Show how you tried to solve the issue

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you closer to what you are trying to do:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Product name')]")
product = element.text.replace("Product name: ", "")
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: This would actually print something like, "\r\nIDE    \r\n\r\n\r\n        Product Price: $499". `.text` would get everything inside the `P` tag... even after the `BR`.